# Thymeleaf SpringMVC page footer doesn't find Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spelevaluationexception

I have a spring boot project that uses SpringMVC and Thymeleaf.  I have a footer defined in a layout.html that is included on every page.  Is there anyway to include a a call on that footer that shows "status" for each page.  This way when you navigate the site, the page footer will always show desired information?

I have a REST Controller that puts a Status object:

```
@Controller
public class StatusController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(Model model) {

    Status status = new Stauts;
    LocalDate lastUpdate = statusRepository.findByLastUpdate();
    ...
     // do some work to update the status object
    model.addAttribute( STATUS, status );
    return "status";
}
```

I have a in my footer.html this defined:

```
  <div th:fragment="foot">
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="muted credit">
            <form action="refreshData" th:action="@{/status}" method="get"></form>
            Last update status: <span th:text="${status.status}" class="text-info"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then each page includes the footer as such:

```
...

<div th:include="layout :: foot"></div>

</body>
```

I put a breakpoint in my controller and its not called, and I always get this exception on page load:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'status' cannot be found on null

I wonder if the Controller is never called because I have to use something like jQuery to make Ajax calls, or because I have this in my layout.html and that include doesn't make calls (which seems unlikely)?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring MVC you only have one controller per page/call. You cannot call several controllers in one shot. I believe this is your issue.

You have multiple possibilites:

- Either you have to incorporate this status variable in each controller yourself.
- create a ControllerAdvice that prepares the model attribute status and is applied to each controller (default)
- use a service call in your footer to fetch the status like: th:text="${@statusService.status}"

I for myself like the service approach for these kind of global available information.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I created a Status Service that just returns a Status object to be read by the page.  This seems to work very well, but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this.  It feels like I am crossing boundries or something.  Maybe I am just surprised at how well this simple solution works :)  Anyway, thank you for the quick and helpful advice.

Comment: You can introduce a custom "Service" annotation like "UIService" and keep these service in the servlet context only. This helps to identify such services for me.

Answer (score 0):

CURRENT:

```
<span th:text="${status.status}" class="text-info">
```

CHANGE TO

```
<span th:text="${status}" class="text-info">
```

this will display null

in the controller you have set Status status = null; and set it in the model map to attribute status".
So ${status} is evaluated as null (this is nothing but model.get("status")). ${status.status} will be null.status .
Resulting in 
'status' cannot be found on null

Comment: Explanation as to the reason for the change would be useful here

Comment: But the Controller is never called so the Status object is never returned.  I'll update my question to show the Status object is instantiated before returning.